# Utilizarse vs Ser utilizado

Tags: gramática, preposiciones, orden-de-palabras, voz-pasiva

En este ejemplo en concreto, ¿cual sería la diferencia?

> Algunos caracteres deben reemplazarse antes de **utilizarse** en el documento.
>
> Algunos caracteres deben reemplazarse antes de **ser utilizados** en el documento.

Comment: La primera emplea el pasivo reflejo, y la segunda la (verdadera) voz pasiva. No hay diferencia en el significado, lo único es que en la primera no se puede mencionar el agente (el que utiliza los caracteres)

Comment: Yo lo que he pensado es que los caracteres es el sujeto, y éstos pueden utilizarse en un documento, pero no pueden ser utilizados en un documento porque "ser utilizados" indica algo asi como que tienen un mecanismo de uso. Por ejemplo un coche no puede utilizarse, pero puede ser utilizado, ya que es alguien el que lo utiliza. ¿Tiene sentido algo de lo que he dicho? :P

Comment: Why not edit your comment into your original question as it may give rise to some expanded comments and answers?

Comment: Aquí hay una exposición sobre las [diferencias entre la pasiva refleja y la perifrástica](http://hispanoteca.eu/Gram%C3%A1ticas/Gram%C3%A1tica%20espa%C3%B1ola/Pasiva%20perifr%C3%A1stica%20con%20ser%20y%20pasiva%20refleja%20con%20se.htm) - gran parte de la cual está en un lenguaje técnico y denso para mí, pero quizá sirva para que alguien arme una respuesta más general.

Comment: Independiente de la gramática, para mi gusto "reemplaz**arse** antes de utiliz**arse**" suena feo.

Comment: @Rodrigo En ese caso, y suponiendo que gramaticalmente sea correcta la otra frase, bien podrías decir: "Algunos caracteres deben **ser reemplazados** antes de utilizarse en el documento."

Comment: @Rodrigo Todas las formas son correctas: (1) "...deben reemplazarse antes de utilizarse...", (2) "...deben ser reemplazados antes de ser utilizados...", (3) "...deben reemplazarse antes de ser utilizados...", (4) "...deben ser reemplazados antes de utilizarse..." La posibilidad de combinar dos pasivas diferentes (como en (3) y en (4)) evita esa aliteración indeseada que mencionas en el caso de (1). (2) resulta algo engorrosa por lo extensa y repetitiva.

Answer (score 1):

Las dos formas son correctas y tienen exactamente el mismo significado.

`ser utilizados` es una pasiva "normal" y `utilizarse` es una pasiva refleja.

Puedes encontrar más información en estos [ejemplos](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voz_pasiva)